# htaccess redirect from folder with subdirectory to single path directoy

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Previously my site was in wordpress, now converted into html.

I have 500+ pdfs that needs to redirect from

`mysite.com/wp-content/themes/my-theme/pdfs` folder to `mysite.com/pdf/`

Comment: I got answer, RewriteRule ^wp-content/themes/my-theme/pdfs/(.*)$ /pdf/$1 [R=301,NC,L]

Answer (score 0):

Do you have server-level access to the site? If so I would [create a symbolic link](https://kb.iu.edu/d/abbe) in the public root directory of your website to `wp-content/themes/my-theme/pdfs` and call it `pdf`.

If all you can do is .htaccess, then you can create a file like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^pdf/(.*)$ /wp-content/themes/my-theme/pdfs /$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

You might check out [a great tutorial](https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/redirecting-a-web-folder-directory-to-another-in-htaccess/) on rewrite rules.

Answer (score 0):

I tried like this it works for me.

RewriteRule ^wp-content/themes/my-theme/pdfs/(.*)$ /pdf/$1 [R=301,NC,L]